# Properties with @Embeddable and @XmlPath(".") are not displayed correctly in JPA-RS metadata

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, moxy, jpa-rs

Given the JPA-RS example [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPARS/Simple), i added a new property for the address to the `Student` class:

```
@Embedded
@XmlPath(".")
private Address address;
```

The `Address` class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Embeddable
public class Address implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String streetName;
    private int streetNumber;
    private int zipCode;
    private String city;

    // constructor, getters, etc.
}
```

When accessing the metadata URL `http://host:port/context-root/persistence/persistence-unit/metadata/entity/Student`, it describes the model without embedding the attributes of the newly added property:

```
{
  "name": "Student",
  "attributes": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "Long"
    },
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "String"
    },
    {
      "name": "address",
      "type": "Address"
    },
    {
      "name": "courses",
      "type": "List<Course>"
    }
  ],
```

But it does work as intended when sending an object like this, also it returns the object in this form using GET:

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "streetName": "Rue Doe",
  "streetNumber": 123,
  "zipCode": 45678,
  "city": "Samplesten"
}
```

My question: Is this an intended behaviour? Let's say i want to use the metadata api to give users knowledge about the general model they have to use. The currect design is extremly misleading. Same applies for renaming an attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in JPA-RS.  I have opened the following bug for this issue:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/425110

Comment: Thanks Blaise, i have another open question on JPA-RS here on SO. I attended a talk by Sean Smith where he encouraged the audience to use JPA-RS. But sadly the documentation is not very extensive and questions in the EL forum over at eclipse.org are rarely answered. Am i missing an important information channel, where i could get quick help for this? Thanks